# Different ListView Behavior In Carousel Causing Content Overflow

Tags: image, listview, canvas, carousel, kivy

I'm LOVING Kivy! Its amazingly powerful! Thanks for all of your hardwork!!

I'm having a bit of an issue where a widget (with a list view) behaves differently depending on if its in set in a carousel. Maybe this is a bug or just a misunderstanding?

This bug only occurs with a custom subclass of Image (similar to example in docs) Which applies a mask.
Maybe i need a scroll calllback or something?

This pictures shows the carousel view at left, the and the profile widget at right.

```
class ProfilesApp(App):

def build(self):
    swiper = Carousel(direction='right')
    with session_scope() as sesh:
        count = sesh.query( User ).count()

    for ct in range(count):
        profile = Profile(user_id = ct + 1)
        swiper.add_widget(profile)

    from kivy.core.window import Window
    Window.size = (iphone['width'],iphone['height'])

    return profile #swiper
```

Here's The Profile Widget. Its just a BoxLayout Container

```
class Profile(Widget):
'''In Which We Display A User'''
_user = None
_image_url = None

def __init__(self, user_id = 1,**kwargs):
    super(Profile,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    #Query Database
    with session_scope() as sesh:
        self._user = sesh.query( User ).get( user_id )
        self._image_url = self._user.picture.locate(store)
        #Free From Session
        sesh.expunge( self._user )

    user_info = ListAdapter(data=self._user.info.split('\n'),\
                            cls = Label)

    #Define Layout
    self._layout = BoxLayout( orientation = 'vertical' )
    self._name = Label( text = self._user.name.upper(), \
                        font_name= os.path.join(EXP_PATH,'hotel_font.ttf'),
                        valign = 'bottom', size_hint = (1,0.15),
                        font_size=38, bold=True,)
    self._image = RoundedImage( source = self.imageLocation)
                                #allow_stretch=True)
    self._info = ListView( adapter = user_info, size_hint = (1,0.6) )

    self._layout.add_widget(self._name)
    self._layout.add_widget(self._image)
    self._layout.add_widget(self._info)

    self.add_widget(self._layout)

    self.bind(pos = self.update_rect,
              size = self.update_rect)

def update_rect(self,*args):
    self._layout.pos = self.pos
    self._layout.size = self.size
```

As mentioned above this problem only occurs with a subclass of Image (similar to example in docs) except it applies a mask, and does some different positioning.

```
Builder.load_string(
'''
<-RoundedImage@Image>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0,0,0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.norm_image_size
            pos: self.center[0] - self.norm_image_size[0]/2.0,self.center[1] - self.norm_image_size[1]/2.0
        StencilPush
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.norm_image_size
            pos: self.center[0] - self.norm_image_size[0]/2.0,self.center[1] - self.norm_image_size[1]/2.0
            radius: self._radius
        StencilUse
        Color:
            rgb: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.norm_image_size
            pos: self.center[0] - self.norm_image_size[0]/2.0,self.center[1] - self.norm_image_size[1]/2.0
        StencilUnUse
        StencilPop''')
#
class RoundedImage(Image):

_radius_pct = 0.5
_radius = [20]

def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(RoundedImage,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.bind(size = self.radius_cmd)
    #self.bind(pos = self.center_image)

def center_image(self, *args):
    print 'centering'
    x,y = self.center
    self.pos =   x - self.norm_image_size[0]/2.0,\
                y - self.norm_image_size[1]/2.0

def radius_cmd(self,*args):
    #if self.height:
    self._radius = [self.height * self._radius_pct]
    #else:
    #    return [10]
```